# Next callback in Backbone Router

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

Is it possible to navigate to the next route handler if the first handler doesn't satisfy/catch a specific situation?

Is something that you can achieve in Express (nodejs) with the `next()`method.

Imagine that you have this router configuration:

```
routes: {
    '*path': 'onPath',
    '*notFound': 'onNotFound'
},

onPath: function(path, next){
    if(path == 'something'){
        console.log('ok');
    } else {
        next();
    }
},

onNotFound: function(){
    console.log('KO');
}
```

I know that I can mix the `onPath` and `onNotFound` methods, but I just want do know if is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why not define an explicit route and handle it then? To the best of my knowledge, you will have to roll your own solution if want to achieve that functionality.

Comment: How about simply redirecting to notFound path when the condition is not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure you can have 2 path matchers in a router.  How would the Router know which to use?  Here is an option.  Remove the notFound route and call the method directly :

```
routes: {
    '*path': 'onPath'
},

onPath: function(path){
    if(path == 'something'){
        console.log('ok');
    } else {
        this.onNotFound(path);
    }
},

onNotFound: function(path){
    console.log('KO');
}
```

Or an even cleaner approach: you can throw an event (avoid too many App level events if you can.  This is just an example)

```
App.trigger("pathNotFound", path);
```

Somewhere else in your code (again, perhaps not at the App level), you will need to listen for this event:

```
App.listenTo("pathNotFound", function(){
               console.log('KO');
});
```

This is all roughly written. You will need to adapt it to your application of course.